# Why the largest singular value of a magic matrix is its magic constant?

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

A magic matrix is a square matrix such that the sums of the elements of each row, each column and diagonal equal to a same number, the `magic constant`.

As reported [here](http://www.ijmttjournal.org/Volume-3/issue-3/IJMTT-V3I3P501.pdf), the largest singular value of a magic matrix is its magic constant.

Can someone provide a proof or an intuition for that?

Comment: Trivially, if $A$ is a magic square with magic constant $M$, then the vector of all $1$'s is an eigenvector of $A^TA$ with eigenvalue $M^2$, so $M$ is a singular value of $A$. Now, how to show it is the largest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like a magic matrix is a special case of a *doubly stochastic matrix*, (and in turn a special case of a *stochastic* matrix), scaled by a scalar value: the *magic constant*.

A stochastic matrix is just a square matrix of nonnegative real numbers with each row summing to $1$.
The *Perron–Frobenius* theorem ensures that every stochastic matrix has an eigenvalue equal to $1$, and that is the eigenvalue with the largest absolute value.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a magic square matrix $\mathbf{A}\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. Denote the magic constant by
$$
s=\frac{n(1+n^2)}{2}.
$$
Since the sum of each row or column equals to $s$, we know that $s$ is a singular value of $\mathbf{A}$, i.e.:
$$
\mathbf{A}^\text{T}\mathbf{Av}=s^2\mathbf{v} \text{, where } \mathbf{v}=[1,\dots,1]^\text{T}.
$$

We know that the singular values of $\mathbf{A}$ satisfy that
$$
\sum_i\sigma_i^2=\text{tr}(\mathbf{A}^\text{T}\mathbf{A})=\sum_i\sum_j a_{ij}^2.
$$
The sum of squares of all entries equals to $\sum_{k=1}^{n^2}k^2=\frac{1}{3}n^6+\frac{1}{2}n^4+\frac{1}{6}n^2$. We have $s^2=\frac{1}{4}n^6+\frac{1}{2}n^4+\frac{1}{4}n^2$, so
$$
\sum_i\sigma_i^2  < 2s^2.
$$
This indicates that all other singular values are smaller than $s$.

Hope this could be helpful.